# how to update flutter web application cached files on each deploy?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I use custom flutter localization with an `en.json` file that contains all of application strings, but after deploying web application for the first time, flutter service worker caches `en.json` and it'll use the first cached `en.json` for all of the next deploys which causes new `Text` widgets that have new strings (that are not in the first `en.json`) fail assertion `data != null`.
Is there a way to force flutter web app to update cached assets after each deploy?

Comment: Does this article help? https://medium.com/flutter-community/caching-in-flutter-for-web-42b3ae0e348f

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the service worker which is runninng in the client background. If you don't need the caching and PWA functionality you can build the app without it.

```
flutter build web --pwa-strategy=none
```

After that you have to make sure that you unregister all service workers from the clients otherwise you will still see the old `en.json`.
You can add this script to your index.html

```html
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
 navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then(function(registrations) {
     for(let registration of registrations) {
       registration.unregister();
     }
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, I need caching in my application. but I need cached files to be updated whenever I release an update.

Comment: I read somewhere that they are working on a solution. Maybe this helps: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55967

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Firestore listener to a specific document or Firebase Remote Config in real time, to check if needs to clear the cache.

Once it needs to clear the webpage cache, simply run:

```
import 'dart:html' as html show window;
html.window.location.reload();
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config